# Pixate Freestyle for iOS - Setting background color to UINavigationBar takes no effect

Tags: ios, css, colors, pixate

I am using Pixate Freestyle CSS rendering framework for iOS.
An issue has been bothering me these days. I tried to set backgroud color to UINavigationBar in one of my project, but it took no effect and the color always turned out white. However, it works in my other new sample projects.
The CSS selector is simple as below:

```
navigation-bar { background-color:#44A2CE; }
```

Are there any possible causes that would make the backgroud color setting for navigation bar fail?
Or is there a way to debug to find some clues?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the background size and see if that helps:

```
navigation-bar {
  background-size:64px;
  background-color:#44A2CE;
}
```

You could also try a gradient and see if that kicks in:

```
navigation-bar {
  background-size:64px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#44A2CE, #44A2CE);
}
```

If that still doesn't work, there might be a problem with your installation of Pixate. If you can post a sample project, I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had tried the first one. No luck. But the second one worked on iOS 7. However, on iOS 6, the status bar will be covered by the navigation bar due to "background-size:64px;".